# Prevent selected value from resetting after POST/submission

Tags: html, ajax, flask

Here I am trying to create a "web dashboard" which takes one parameter `year_from`  from the HTML form. And my Flask backend should return the data within this range. However, I found that every time I hit submit, the selected values will be reset to the first option in the select and the backend always returns the data from the first option, please advise how I can get this fixed? any help is appreciated.

Here is my HTML:

```
<form class="select-year" method="post" name="form1"/>
        <label>Year From</label>
        <select name="year_pop_category" class="form-control mx-sm-3 my-2" id="year_pop_category"/>
            <option value="2016">2016</option>
            <option value="2017">2017</option>
            <option value="2018">2018</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary my-2">GO!</button>
</form>
```

--update:

I have tried using ajax to but the when `submit` button is clicked, the webpage still reloads and the user input still gets reset. How do I get the ajax call to work?

Here is my ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('form1').on('submit', function(e) {
            $.ajax({
                data: {
                    year_from: $('#year_pop_category').val()
                },
                type : 'POST',
                url : '/product',
                success : function(result){
                     alert(result.output);
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

I am new to JS and ajax, Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You should try sent your form with Ajax without refreshing the page. Or rather get your properties back with GET. Like read get properties on back end response and then pass them to the form like <option value="2016" selected>2016</option>

Answer (score 0):

1. Your form does not have an `action` attribute (you have not specified the route that will receive and process the form). I believe the default when you don't specify a value is for the system to replace it with an empty string which means your form contents may really not be going to the server. Add `action = "/product"` to the form and try again.
2. If you submit the form directly, it will reload your page. To prevent reloading your page, you should use Ajax (which you have tried to do) but since you are using jquery, you should specify an Id for your form and use the id in the ajax code i.e.

form

```
<form class="select-year" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" />
```

```
$('#form1').on('submit', function(e)
...
```

You can also keep your code as is and submit using the form tag i.e. you're asking jquery to submit the element whose tag is `<form>`

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e)
```